# Does a motor driver need a ground reference for logic signal with optocoupler isolation on logic pins?

Tags: motor, opto-isolator, motordriver

I am using two power supplies, one for the motor driver (+24v), and the other one for my MCU (+5v).

My concern is that in the datasheet of the motor driver ([DRV8871](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf)) it is mentioned that GND needs to be connected to the logic supply GND and PGND need to be connected to the high power GND, but I have connected PGND and GND of the motor driver to the same GND (GND 1).

So technically it should not work, but what if I use an optocoupler as isolation with two different GND (GND, PGND) on the logic pins of the driver; will it work?

[All images related to my circuit](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qgMje9aKUdDEBcI4VA5baGcJ2s4_Zu83?usp=sharing)

Comment: The ground of the 24V Supply, the ground of the 5V supply, PGND on the DRV8871, and GND on the DRV8871 all need to be connected together.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to share ground with MCU so optocoupler will not help? , could please tell me the reason?

Comment: Oh, if you do not want to share the ground then you can use an optocoupler. The output of the optocoupler becomes the logic as far as the DRV8871 is concerned so the GND on the optocoupler output needs to be connected to the DRV8871's GND

Comment: "I have connected PGND and GND of the motor driver to same GND (GND 1) so technically it should not work ", technically it has to be like that and the only way to make it working.

Comment: @DKNguyen It is not working  I am getting voltages on optocoupler output pin but driver is not driving motor but when I directly connect logic pin to the driver without any optocoupler circuitry using same ground it start driving motor

Comment: Google Drive - what a POS it is! Please put the schematics in your post where we can see them.